# Open PDF in new window/Tab from server side

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, window.open

I'm trying to open a PDF in a new tab/window, I'm passing a string format to the browser. The file is the path to the file, it's not working

```
file = "\\QA_APP_SRV\WebsiteDocs\FIR\FileSharing\PatronUploads\MSR\987874.40029976.pdf"
var url = string.Format(@"<a href=" + file + " target='_blank'> Link</a>");
```

*When I post the URL in the browser it renders, but because of the space in the URL it doesn't render when I click on it

Comment: post what file variable contains , it has to be a url

Comment: it cannot be the local path, it has to be a url  ( EG:  www.yourerbsite.com/filelocation/987874.40029976.pdf

 )

Comment: Space shouldn't be issue here it's something else. How are you rendering this on the view?